# Same request that works with requests fails using urequests

Tags: request, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I am working on a panel to show the metro timetable of Valencia. The plan is to use a Raspberry Pi Pico W and some character displays. I wrote the Python code to run it from my computer:

```
import requests

url = 'https://www.metrovalencia.es/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
myobj = {'action': 'formularios_ajax',
        'data': f"action=horarios-ruta&\
origen=100&\
destino=101&\
dia=2022-11-12&\
horaDesde=10:00&\
horaHasta=23:59"}

req = requests.post(url, data = myobj)
print(req.status_code)
```

This prints `200` and works. I want to execute it on the Raspberry Pi Pico W:

```
import network
import urequests
import ujson

wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
wlan.active(True)
wlan.connect("SSID", "PASSW")
ntptime.settime()

print(wlan.isconnected())

url = 'https://www.metrovalencia.es/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php'
myobj = {'action': 'formularios_ajax',
        'data': f"action=horarios-ruta&\
origen=88&\
destino=91&\
dia=2022-11-12&\
horaDesde=10:00&\
horaHasta=23:59"}

req = urequests.post(url, data = ujson.dumps(myobj))
print(req.status_code)
```

It prints `True` and `400` so connection was made, but the request did not work. URL and data are the same in both examples. Why does this happen? Due to limitations of Raspberry Pi Pico, difference between requests and urequests packages, a missing token on Raspberry Pi Pico?

Comment: Try adding this keyword argument to your request: ‘headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}’

Comment: Same status code, nothing changed.